# <th> background shows incorrectly as border around table caption

Tags: html, css, outlook-2010

I have an issue with HTML/CSS rendering in Outlook 2010.

The below HTML renders correctly in all other email clients I have tested (Thunderbird, Outlook 2003, iPhone, various webmail based products), and in various browsers too. But in Outlook 2010 I get a border around the table caption that is the same colour as the background for the  tag below it.

[image: HTML table with caption in Outlook 2010]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div style="padding: 0.3em">
    <p>Here is a nice background from St Pancras Station with the Olympic Rings in the background</p>
    <hr />

    <table style=" width: auto; color: #000; border: 1px solid #000; border-collapse: collapse; background: #FFF;">
      <caption style=" font-style: italic; text-align: left; color: #000; background: #FFF;">Files attached to this message</caption>
      <tr>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; background: #ddd;  text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Filename</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; background: #ddd;  text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Size</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 75%;">6315755363_7fbe95fc66_o.jpg</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;">5 MB</td>
      </tr>

    </table>

    <p>Please <a href="https://********/message/Hreh4oqPUR9ctdJ59Nkm4N">click here</a> to download the attachments.</p>

    <p>The attachments are available until: <b>Tuesday, 11 December.</b></p>
    <hr />
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone suggest a fix for this issue?

**EDIT**

If you want to debug this you can save the HTML in a file and load it into Word 2010 as it uses the same rendering engine.

Comment: Take the `background: #FFF;` off of your caption tag style and the bg of the caption will be gray and it won't look like there is a border.

Comment: But I want a white background not grey

Comment: try setting `<table border=0>` and removing the border from the table styling. Captions are technically part of the table so the border styling is going to be applied to it as well.

Comment: Or even `border: none;` inside the style for the caption

Comment: `border: none` won't fix it and `<table boarder=0>` is not even the correct syntax.

Comment: @ChristianVarga I tried that too, to no avail. I don't think it is a border issue but more likely an issue with background colour from the `<th>` tag

Comment: its surely not a background and a border?  `border: 0px solid #FFF;`

Comment: @MikeT: Of course it's not when you're spelling it wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock my mistake but I did spell it correctly in the HTML file, God bless code complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div style="padding: 0.3em">
    <p>Here is a nice background from St Pancras Station with the Olympic Rings in the background</p>
    <hr />
    <table style=" width: auto; color: #000;  border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #fff; border-bottom-color: #000; background: #fff; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <caption style=" font-style: italic; text-align: left; color: #000;">Files attached to this message</caption>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; background: #ddd;  text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Filename</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; background: #ddd;  text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Size</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 75%;background: #FFF;">6315755363_7fbe95fc66_o.jpg</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;background: #FFF;">5 MB</td>
      </tr>

    </table>

    <p>Please <a href="https://********/message/Hreh4oqPUR9ctdJ59Nkm4N">click here</a> to download the attachments.</p>

    <p>The attachments are available until: <b>Tuesday, 11 December.</b></p>
    <hr />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For anyone still stumbling across this question, this marked answer is and always has been invalid HTML. The <caption> element is only valid directly after the opening <table> tag, even back in HTML 4.01.

[HTML 4.01 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.2)
[HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-caption-element)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding phantom row after `<caption>`

```
<caption style=" font-style: italic; text-align: left; color: #000; background: #FFF;">Files attached to this message</caption>
<tr style="background:#FFF; display:none;"></tr> <!--phantom row-->
<tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; background: #ddd;  text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Filename</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.3em; background: #ddd;  text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Size</th>
</tr>
```